# How to call a DB2 AS400 table valued function which take Date parameters

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-functions, db2-400

I have a table valued function as below

```
  CREATE FUNCTION ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS (STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE, ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9))
        RETURNS TABLE (ID INT, JOBNUMBER CHAR(9), CUSTOMERREFERENCE CHAR(18), 
        CONSIGNEENAME CHAR(30), CREATEDDATE DATE, AIRPORTOFORIGIN CHAR(3), AIRPORTOFARRIVAL CHAR(3),
        AIRPORTOFDESTINATION CHAR(3), COUNTRYOFDESTINATION CHAR(3), ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9), CONSIGNMENTNUMBER CHAR(25))
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        READS SQL DATA
        RETURN
            SELECT  
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMJOBN DESC),  
                     A.EMJOBN,  
                     A.EMCREF,  
                     A.EMOSNM,
                     DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')),  
                     A.EMAOFO,  
                     A.EMAOFA,  
                     A.EMAOFD,  
                     A.EMCOFD,  
                     A.EMUKCD,
                     A.EMRPRT 
                     FROM DTALIBLE.EMASTER A WHERE A.EMPSFT = 'Y' AND A.EMUKCD = ADDRESSCODE AND 
                     DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')) >= DATE(STARTDATE) AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(A.EMCRTD), 'DDMMYY')) <= DATE(ENDDATE)
```

However I am not getting any results back when I run the following query

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS(DATE('06/06/2019'), DATE('06/07/2020'),'MUL0044')) AS XXX
```

I am using DBeaver to run the query on AS400.

For my own sanity I tired the select statement with literals and i got the following result
[image]

Then again when I tried with below dates it does not fetch any results and i get this error.

[image]

any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the result if you run the same query as in the SELECT statement of the function, using literal values as supplied to the function (with dates in ISO format )

Comment: I'm curious about the relationship between this question and C#

Comment: the format you use is mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy check the difference with `values to_char('06/07/2020', 'dd month yyyy'), to_char('06.07.2020', 'dd month yyyy')`

Comment: Or learn to use ISO formats in your date literals and why that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out at me is that in your invocation,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS(DATE('06/06/2019'), DATE('06/07/2020'),'MUL0044')) AS XXX
```

`'MUL0044'` as a literal is treated as varchar, and your UDTF has the parm defined as char.

That mismatch usually gives a Function not found error however.  You can cast the literal to char or change the parm type to varchar.  Which to chose depends on how it will normally be invoked.  If you're just testing with a literal and the function would normally be passed a char then just cast the literal to char.

If you use the Run SQL Scripts component of IBM ACS, you'll have the ability to debug the function.